# How to answer a question when the only possible path of research leads to a dead end?

Tags: discussion

Recently, @Gerrit posted the question [Did an American kindergarten teach children the alphabet using corporate logos?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/44190/did-an-american-kindergarten-teach-children-the-alphabet-using-corporate-logos)  Everything seems to be in order with regards to the question, with @Gerrit providing a picture and links to both Reddit and Facebook where the picture was received, with many users expressing shock and outrage.  The photo was also found on KnowYourMemes as well, showing that the image has gained some traction on the internet as a whole.

Upon doing some research, I was able to track the source of the image back to a post on Reddit from 9 months ago.  Within the thread, there are no attempts to actually fact check the validity of the image, and the OP refuses to provide any more evidence for the validity of the photos, only commenting 3 times, making another unsubstantiated claim and talking about the photo.

---

> Per the same person that shared these (which are legit) they also sell advertising space on school issued folders. Five hundred bucks gets your logo stickered real big to the front and assigned to the kid at some point.

---

> X is Xbox lol, I cropped it to fit the two rows in

---

> They didn't want to dox themselves, but they said it was public (note: this was in regards another user asking what school this photo was from)

I see one of three different possibilities for this question.

1. Leave the question unanswered until the question can be definitively answered "YES" or "NO", and with my comments regarding the lack of research avenues left on the question itself.
2. Close the question for lacking notability since the original source of the image is an anonymous user on Reddit
3. Post an answer outlining the source of the photo and the inability to track down the source, with an answer of "Inconclusive" or something similar.

What is the best course of action here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would suggest point 3. Your reference research is useful and it's OK not to reach a conclusion.

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1, acceptable**: Leave the question unanswered.

In a way every user does it until they actively decide to post an answer, regardless of the amount of research they do. Leaving a question unanswered doesn't make it a bad question, it just means that no-one found the answer so far.

**Option 2, not acceptable**: Close the question for lacking notability.

The fact that you cannot find a definite answer has nothing to do with the notability of a claim. That would be like getting asked "Does 2 + 3 equal 6?" and answering "Your question is invalid". No, the question is still valid, the answer might just not be what the other person expected.

The poster provided links to social media where this exact claim is spread among a not-negligible number of people and is now questioning it's credibility. *This is exactly what Sceptics.SE is here for*.

**Option 3, preferable**: Post an inconclusive answer.

In my personal oppinion, any information is better than no information. Outlining the lack of credibility is a valuable information for any person already being sceptic of the claim. If you cannot draw a final conclusion, leave it up to the reader, but try to give them all the information they need for that.

**Option 4**: Don't write an answer if you don't have an answer.

On other Stacks it's not uncommon for users to post little bits of information in comments to the question instead of an answer. This option has more disadvantages than advantages, though.

You get the chance to offer your information even if it doesn't answer the question, but on the other hand, you circumvent the voting mechanism of StackExchange and moderators may delete your comment without warning at a later time to clean up the post.